# RewriteCond redirect to subdomain not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I cant make the rule to redirect the web page to a subdomain:

if the url starts with `/tag` like this:

```
http://www.my-website.com/tag/music
```

it should be redirected to:

```
http://blog.my-website.com/tag/music
```

I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/tag/?(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.fr/tag/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

but it not redirecting.. it stays on www.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @casperOne why this got closed?? O_O there are more than 5000 questions about RewriteCond on S.O.

Comment: These questions are handled on ServerFault.  As for the others, no question being open is a justification for any other question being open.  This question is off topic as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you should be using in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^tag/ http://blog.my-website.fr%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.my-website\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tag/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/tag/?(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.fr/tag/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

oooh k... remove the extra `?` from the rule and should work.

```
RewriteRule ^/tag/(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.fr/tag/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: It makes an internal server error.. i think that's because the subdomain also uses this rule and it ends up in an infinite loop

Comment: in that case, you can use multiple ReWriteCond clauses. One for checking the domain.

Comment: and how do i do that? I'm kinda new in this :P

Comment: there is no internal server error now.. but it's still not redirecting u____U

Answer (score 0):

If this in an `.htaccess` file you mustn't have the leading / in RewriteRule patterns:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/?(.*)$ http://blog.my-website.fr/tag/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```